# Trying to get image source out of plist

Tags: ios, plist

in my plist (dictionary entries) i would like to store a path to an image for each item 
like so:

```
<key>Image</key>
<string>sit_109_111.jpg</string>
```

In the app, i would like to set the image source (UIImageView) to that image 
What do i need to do to convert the value to be able to set it to the uiimageview.image property?

I tried doing this

```
  self.exerciseImage.image=[self.exerciseDetail objectForKey:IMAGE_KEY];
```

and it crashes

fixed it

```
  self.exerciseImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.exerciseDetail objectForKey:IMAGE_KEY]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are reading your plist file into a dictionary like so

```
NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

You can do

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [plistDict objectForKey:@"Image"]];
[self.exerciseImage setImage:image];
```